# Manipulate data when exporting to CSV?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter v2.2.4

Consider the following code to export/download a CSV file representing results from a database query.

**CONTROLLER**:

```
public function export_csv($id = NULL)
{   
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $query = $this->my_model->create_csv($id);  // call the model

    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ',');

    force_download( $id . '.csv', $data );
}
```

**MODEL**:

```
public function create_csv($id)
{
    $this->db->from('mytable');

    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $this->db->select('
        id            AS `ID`,
        full_name     AS `Full Name`,
        company_name  AS `Company Name`,
        phone         AS `Phone Number`,
        select_list   AS `User Options`
    ', FALSE);

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

The code above is working, however the `select_list` value is `0`, `1`, or `2` and that's inserted into the CSV export.  How can I manipulate these values into more meaningful text for my final CSV file?

Example:

```
'DB value' => 'insert into CSV'
         0 => 'N/A',
         1 => 'foo',
         2 => 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a select statement along these lines

```
$this->db->select(
   "id            AS `ID`,
    full_name     AS `Full Name`,
    company_name  AS `Company Name`,
    phone         AS `Phone Number`,
    CASE select_list WHEN = 1 THEN 'foo' WHEN = 2 THEN 'bar' ELSE 'N/A' END
    AS `User Options`", FALSE);
```

CANCEL THAT! It is wrong.

It should be as follows when using the optional `expression` after CASE, i.e. `CASE select_list ...`

```
$this->db->select(
   "id            AS `ID`,
    full_name     AS `Full Name`,
    company_name  AS `Company Name`,
    phone         AS `Phone Number`,
    CASE select_list WHEN 1 THEN 'foo' WHEN 2 THEN 'bar' ELSE 'N/A' END
    AS `User Options`", FALSE);
```

I was mixing the different forms the statement can use in the first (incorrect) example.

Comment: Getting a database error for some reason.  Error Number: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1 THEN 'foo' WHEN = 2 THEN 'bar' ELSE 'N/A' END AS `User Options`,' at line 1

Comment: Not sure what your field datatypes are. Try single-quoting the values  e.g. `WHEN = '1'`

Comment: Datatype is not the issue.  `CASE select_list WHEN = 1` was the issue.  Had to use `CASE WHEN select_list = 1`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact syntax that worked for me...

```
$this->db->select("
    id            AS `ID`,
    full_name     AS `Full Name`,
    company_name  AS `Company Name`,
    phone         AS `Phone Number`,
    CASE
        WHEN select_list = 1 THEN 'foo' 
        WHEN select_list = 2 THEN 'bar' 
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END           AS `User Options`
", FALSE);
```

this variation also works...

```
$this->db->select("
    id            AS `ID`,
    full_name     AS `Full Name`,
    company_name  AS `Company Name`,
    phone         AS `Phone Number`,
    CASE select_list
        WHEN 1 THEN 'foo' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'bar' 
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END           AS `User Options`
", FALSE);
```

Comment: Good one. I think I mixed my syntaxes. The expression after CASE is optional. Without it your answer is correct. See my amended answer.